# winsock: connect fails with error 10049 when using localhost (127.0.0.1)

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, winsock

I wrote a class encapsulating some of the winsock functions to imitate a simple TCP socket for my needs...

When I try to run a simple connect-and-send-data-to-server test the "client" fails on its call to connect with the error code of 10049 (WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL) [connect function on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

What I am doing is (code below):
**Server:**

1. Create a Server Socket -> Bind it to *Port 12345*
2. Put the Socket in listen mode
3. Call accept

**Client**

1. Create a socket -> Bind it to a random port
2. Call Connect: connect to *localhost, port 12345*

=> the call to connect fails with Error 10049, as described above

**Here is the main function including the "server":**

```
HANDLE hThread = NULL;
Inc::CSocketTCP ServerSock;
Inc::CSocketTCP ClientSock;

try
{

    ServerSock.Bind(L"", L"12345");
    ServerSock.Listen(10);

    //Spawn the senders-thread
    hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(nullptr, 0, Procy, nullptr, 0, nullptr);

    //accept
    ServerSock.Accept(ClientSock);


    //Adjust the maximum packet size
    ClientSock.SetPacketSize(100);


    //receive data
    std::wstring Data;
    ClientSock.Receive(Data);

    std::wcout << "Received:\t" << Data << std::endl;
}
catch(std::exception& e)
{...
```

**Client thread function**

```
unsigned int WINAPI Procy(void* p)
```

{

```
Sleep(1500);
try{
    Inc::CSocketTCP SenderSock;
    SenderSock.Bind(L"", L"123456");

    SenderSock.Connect(L"localhost", L"12345");


    //Adjust packet size
    SenderSock.SetPacketSize(100);

    //Send Data
    std::wstring Data = L"Hello Bello!";
    SenderSock.Send(Data);
}
catch(std::exception& e)
{
    std::wcout << e.what() << std::endl;
}...
```

**The Connect-Function**

```
    int Inc::CSocketTCP::Connect(const std::wstring& IP, const std::wstring& Port)
{
    //NOTE: assert that the socket is valid
    assert(m_Socket != INVALID_SOCKET);

    //for debuggin: convert WStringToString here
    std::string strIP = WStringToString(IP), strPort = WStringToString(Port);

    Incgetaddrinfo AddyResolver;
    addrinfo hints = {}, *pFinal = nullptr;
    
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;

    //resolve the ip/port-combination for the connection process
    INT Ret = AddyResolver(strIP.c_str(), strPort.c_str(), &hints, &pFinal);
    if(Ret)
    {
        //error handling: throw an error description
        std::string ErrorString("Resolving Process failed (Connect): ");
        ErrorString.append(Inc::NumberToString<INT>(Ret));
        throw(std::runtime_error(ErrorString.c_str()));
    }


    /*---for debbuging---*/
    sockaddr_in *pP = (sockaddr_in*)(pFinal->ai_addr);
    u_short Porty = ntohs(pP->sin_port);
    char AddBuffer[20] = "";

    InetNtopA(AF_INET, (PVOID)&pP->sin_addr, AddBuffer, 20);
    /*--------------------------------------------------------*/


    if(connect(m_Socket, pFinal->ai_addr, pFinal->ai_addrlen) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        int ErrorCode = WSAGetLastError();
        if((ErrorCode == WSAETIMEDOUT) || (ErrorCode == WSAEHOSTUNREACH) || (ErrorCode == WSAENETUNREACH))
        {
            //Just Unreachable
            return TCP_TARGETUNREACHABLE;
        }

        //real errors now
        std::string ErrorString("Connection Process failed: ");
        ErrorString.append(Inc::NumberToString<int>(ErrorCode));
        throw(std::runtime_error(ErrorString.c_str()));
    }

    return TCP_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Additional Information:**
-Incgetaddrinfo is a function object encapuslating getaddrinfo...
-Noone of the server functions return any error and work as expected when stepping through them using the debugger or when letting them run solely...

I'd be glad to hear your suggestions what the problem might be...

It works when I **dont** connect to `("localhost","12345")`, **but** to `("",12345)`...
When look into the address resolution process of `getaddrinfo` it gives **127.0.0.1** for `"localhost"` and my **real IP** for `""`

Why doesn't it work with my loopback-IP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the answer in your question:

> ... it gives `127.0.0.1` for `"localhost"` and my real IP for `""`

This means your server binds to the real IP of the interface instead of `INADDR_ANY`, i.e. it doesn't listen on the loopback.

#### Edit 0:

You don't really need name resolution when creating listening socket. Just `bind()` it to `INADDR_ANY` to listen on all available interfaces (including the loopback).

Comment: but i did try it already with binding to localhost, to which the client could not connect, too... i also tried deactivating the windows firewall...

Comment: `netstat -na` will show what ports are being listened on on what addresses. IIRC `-b` option on Windows will show you what programs use what connections.

Comment: ok... when i bind to "" (INADDR_ANY because of AI_PASSIVE in the hints of getaddrinfo) it binds to the 192..... and is listening on that ip with port 12345 (netstat -na)
=>trying to connect via "" works , but localhost fails...

binding the server socket to localhost makes it listen on 127.0.0.1 (netstat) => connecting via "" fails, and via localhost fails too...

Comment: "Dude", yes i did - as described above - by passing an empty string to getaddrinfo and using the flag AI_PASSIVE (msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738520(v=vs.85) => downwards to the Flag Bits table)

Comment: ok, found the problem... when using name resolution it seems, that passing "" to getaddrinfo doesnt work anymore as it did, or it did work luckyly for me in past times...

you have to pass NULL/nullptr, that it works... added this using (strIP.empty()? nullptr : strIP.c_str())

thx for all your help and patience!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this error was caused by not calling `htonl` on `INADDR_LOOPBACK` before assigning it to `address.sin_addr.s_addr`.

Make sure you convert to network byte order, or you'll get `0x0100007f (1.0.0.127)` instead of `0x7f000001 (127.0.0.1)` for your loopback address and the bind will fail with code `10049 (WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL)`.